# Python Matplotlib can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, matplotlib, integer, pie-chart

```
df3 =pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(by="continent")['total_cases'].sum())
df3
```

This is my code and output : [image]

and I want to calculate the total case for each continent and draw a pie chart.I'm writing the following code and I get an error can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 8))
plt.title('Total case for each continent')

plt.pie(df3.total_cases,df3.index,shadow=True, autopct='%1.1f%%',startangle=90)
plt.show()
```

This is error picture : [image]

When I searched, I read and tried converting int would be useful. But I couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: You probably want to add the `labels=` argument name: `plt.pie(df3.total_cases,  labels=df3.index, ...)`. If you don't set the argument name, the second argument will be `explode=`, which gets very confusing with a list of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @JohanC suggested, you should do this:

```
plt.pie(df3.total_cases,labels=df3.index,shadow=True, autopct='%1.1f%%',startangle=90)
```

otherwise matplotlib is considering `df.index` to be passed to `explode` and cause the error.